# How to call a c++ function without including the header file and duplication?

Tags: c++, call, header-files, code-duplication

I am doing C++ coding.

From file f2.cpp, I need to call a function f1()  defined in f1.cpp but not deleared in f1.h.

I cannot do it by including the f1.h in f2.cpp.

I do not want to define another function that does the same thing, it is duplication.

How to solve this problem ?

Thanks

**UPDATED**

After reading the solutions, I am going to add the declearation of f1() in f1.h.

in f1.h, it has

```
namespace name1{
   namespace name2{
      class class1{};
      class class2{};
   }
}
```

f1() is just an utility function that does not touch members of clas1 and class2.

Currently, f1() is defined within a namespace (without a name) in f1.cpp.

```
namespace{
  f1(){

  }
}
```

But, in f1.h, it has a namespace defination name1 and name2.

Where should I put f1() declearation in f1.h ?

Now, I put f1() in name1::name2 in f1.h and included f1.h in f2.cpp, i got link error:
undefiend name1::name2::f1() from f2().

**UPDATED** 
If I put delaration of f1() in f1.h outside any namespace and also include f1.h from f2.cpp, i got link error: undefined symbol of f1() in f2(), why ?

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: "I cannot do it by including the f1.h in f2.h." - why so?

Comment: @H2CO3 Because it's not declared in f1.h. A better question is: why can't you declare f1 in f1.h?

Comment: @ThomasDarr I actually meant that. Yep.

Comment: You can redeclare "void f1();" in f2.cpp. But normally you should put it to f1.h.

Comment: Can't you declare function header in f1.h, and then include f1.h in f2.cpp?

Comment: @Thomas Darr, there are two namespaces in f1.h. I am not sure where I should put decleration in f1.h. Any good ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

Declare the function as extern in f2.cpp

```
//f2.cpp    
extern void f();   //function declared but defined elsewhere

int main() {    
    f();
}

//f1.cpp
void f() {    
   //function declaration    
}
```

g++ f2.cpp f1.cpp , would work fine.

Having said that, you could also do a #include of f2.cpp, which would work but is definitely a bad idea, because if you compile both files together you will multiple definition error. If in your control the right thing would be to have a f1.h with the function declaration.

UPDATE: For your modified question using namespaces, by using unnamed-namespace around f() you are explicitly telling the compiler to restrict the visibility of the function to just that file. You could change to a named namespace and then refer to its declaration in header file

Comment: thanks ! f() is defined in a namespace{} in f1.cpp, can extern still work in this way ?

Comment: Ah I didnot see the namespace part, since you are using unnamed-namespace you are explicitly making the function not visible outside of f1.cpp. You could move it to a named namespace and refer it from outside

Comment: No need for the `extern` on `f`, really. Functions are `extern` by default.

Comment: @jayadev, how to put f1() in g1.h with 2 namespaces ? Currently, f1() is only called from f1.cpp, after change, f1() will be called from f1.cpp and f2.cpp, so f2() (in f2.cpp) will need to use name1::mane2::f1() from f2.cpp, right ? What if I put f1() in f1.h but outside any of namespaces, and add f1.h  in f2.cpp ? Is this a good solution ?

Comment: I got same issue as ops

Answer (score 1):

The utility function you want to use is in an anonymous namespace, which is similar in concept to a `static`. It makes the function only visible to that source file.

If you do not want to move the function out of `f1.cpp`, then you need to make the interface to the utility function public in some way. One way is to move the function into a new namespace that has a name, something like `f1_util` perhaps. Then you can declare the presence of the utility function in `f1.h`.

```
// f1.cpp
namespace {
    // move f1() out of this
}
namespace f1_util {
  void f1(){
    //...
  }
}
using namespace f1_util;
//... rest of f1.cpp

// f1.h
namespace f1_util {
    void f1();
}
//... rest of f1.h
```

Better may be to move the utility function into a new source file, say, `util.cpp`, and make sure it is not in an anonymous namespace. Then define a `util.h` that declares it. Then have both `f1.cpp` and `f2.cpp` include the `util.h`.

Comment: Thanks! But, f1() is defined in a namespace that also has other functions definations. I do not want to impact them. I only need to make f1() can be called from f2.cpp.

Comment: @user2420472: Can you move it out to a new namespace? Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks! , I cannot make a new file util.h. If I put f1() declearation in f1.h (with 2 namespaces), whaht will be the impact ?

Comment: There shouldn't be any as far as `f1.c` is concerned. It should find the function. But, the visible impact is that `f1()` becomes a function that can be accessed from `f2.c`.

Answer (score 0):

Put the declaration of `f1()` in `f2.cpp`. The location of a declaration doesn't matter to the compiler, it's just a programming convention that declarations and definitions get put in corresponding header and source files.  It's a good practice to follow, though: if you change the header of a function in `f1.cpp`, you only have to update that declaration in `f1.h`, you don't have to look for it in all the other `.cpp` files that call the function. This is the reason we use header files in the first place, for modularity.

Comment: Now, I put f1() in name1::name2 in f1.h and included f1.h in f2.cpp, i got link error:
undefiend name1::name2::f1() from f2(). 

Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just include f1.cpp or declare the function in f1.h?